# search in strings to find word with preg match all and regex

Tags: php, search, preg-match-all

i am trying to code a search function to search in strings and find the word

like the php + mysql for example

```
Select * From Column Where ID Like %Word%
```

i tried to code the same idea with Preg match all and regex

Here is my code

```
$strings = '
( monstername 205 "Devil Troop of Desire")
( monstername 206 "  Devil Troop of Pain     "  )
( monstername 207       "Devil Troop of Greed")
( monstername 208   "       Devil Troop of Jealousy  ")
( monstername 207 "Mask Troop of Greed"  )';

preg_match_all('/monstername\s*(.*?)\s*\"\s*\\b(Jealousy)\b\s*\"\s*\)/i', $strings, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match){list (, $MonsterNumber) = $match;
echo "$MonsterNumber";
}
```

the output should be

```
208
```

but it dont display the output correct

it display it when i replace **Jealousy** With **Devil Troop of Jealousy**

i just want to do the same idea of php + mysql

Where ID Like %Word%

without give the full string to find the number of monster

Comment: My regex skills aren't too bad right now as i was using regex yesterday in PHP. However, my problem is trying to understand what you're trying to do, why would the output be 208? If it was like mysql you would have the number of rows that match but getting 208 is like returning ONE result using MAX() :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `"\s*\\b(Jea` does not allow for other characters than whitespace between the quote and the start of the word. You probably wanted any char (or even none?) between them, like `".*\\b(Jea` and the same problem after the word.

Comment: well, it worked fine but it that possible to write only Jea  Like ".*\\b(Jea)\b.*\"  and get output, because i tried but it didnt work, and this is a search script

Answer (score 0):

You have to better define what you are searching for: before and after Jealousy you may have space/non-space, non-quote characters.

```
preg_match_all('/\( monstername\s*(\d+)\s*"\s*([^"]*\bJealousy\b[^"]*)\s*"\s*\)/i',
$strings, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Or to use in a search script,

```
preg_match_all('/\( monstername\s*(\d+)\s*"\s*([^"]*(Jealousy)[^"]*)\s*"\s*\)/i',
$strings, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

For each matching monster it will return matching row, monster number, monster name and matched pattern:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ( monstername 208   "       Devil Troop of Jealousy  ")
            [1] => 208
            [2] => Devil Troop of Jealousy
            [3] => Jealousy
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you only want the monster number as output, this regex matches only the number and nothing around it because of the lookahead and lookbehind:

```
/(?<=monstername\s)\d+(?=.*Jealousy.*)/i
```

But with this you can only have one whitespace character betwenn "monstername" and the number.